# Adding a margin to a StartApp advertisement?

Tags: android, layout, startapp

I've recently integrated [StartApp](http://developers.startapp.com/) into my app. Now, I don't want the Ads to be full size, I want them with a small margin on each side. Now I didn't change much about my layout as I am working with libGDX, so I didn't have to care about XML files before. That's what my main.xml looks like:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.startapp.android.publish.banner.Banner 
    android:id="@+id/startAppBanner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, I've tried all kinds of things like adding `android:layout_margin="10dp"` or `android:padding="10dp"` to the `Banner` or the `LinearLayout`, but that doesn't change a thing. So my question is: Is there any way to achieve what I'm looking for, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'wrap_content' for the 'layout_width' and 'layout_height', then layout_margin should work.

The following works for me:

```
<com.startapp.android.publish.banner.Banner 
    android:id="@+id/startAppBanner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
/>
```